# Make sure a total can not become greater than the initial amount

Tags: google-sheets-formula

This is being built as a combat calculator for a game. So A3:A5 create the value in A2 which shows in A42. I need A42 to not rise above the number in A2 when A40:A41 make their additions and subtractions.Thank you for any assistance you have to offer.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bfCrPDsRJM1EV6Lw5b6rOTaGR6lY1T14TZry9LJi1Kk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The sheet in question is **Combat Calculations**, right? `A:A` column just has the headers, so you must be talking about the corresponding rows (`B2:2` for example), correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula put into `A42` will give you current health, but no more than maximum possible (all to the right from `A42` should be cleared (it was done on your sheet)):

```
={
  "Total Health",
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      B2:Q2 < B2:Q2 - B40:Q40 + B41:Q41,
        B2:Q2,
        B2:Q2 - B40:Q40 + B41:Q41
    )
  )
}
```

But it might be less than 0. You could easily fix that if needed.

Also I put similar formulas in `A2` for max health, `A40` for total damage, and `A41` for total heals. Again, all to the right from those cells should be cleared (also done).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much, this worked out great. I am not sure if you know but is it possible for the drop down in B10:Q10 to generate a specific number in B4 and B5 depending on selection made?

Comment: Sure, it is possible.

Comment: @FirecageZaid You have different data validation rules (they define drop-down menu's content) for cells in the row `10:10`. Which should it be: `Tables!A:A` or `Tables!B:B`? HP Class Buff is just `Tables!C:C`?

Comment: B4:Q4 should use BonusHP, while B5:Q5 should use OtherBonus

The drop should be using Tables!B

Comment: @FirecageZaid ok, it is done. Quite simple usage of `ARRAYFORMULA` and `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: I just saw, thank you so very much.This was a ton of help.

Comment: Would it be the same formula to have the drop down for name to generate the race column?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do a little adaptation, but no principal difference